# How can I extract route alert data from Waze?

Tags: data-analysis, waze

I've just made a long car travel and Waze gave me great alerts about the road quality. I'd like to share this info with the oversight authorities. Some of the roads were really bad and Waze informed about the road spots that needed maintenance.

Is it possible to extract the alerts in a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waze has the [Waze for Cities](https://www.waze.com/wazeforcities) program that allows governmental institutions to retrieve the alerts from Waze users. Some cities already use this program to see where potholes are reported most often, to get an idea of where they need to focus on their road repairs. But it's not a plug-and-play system that just gives them that information. There is access to the data feeds and a way to start gathering historical data from that point on, but some of it requires technical knowledge to set it up.

Retrieving your own personal alerts can be done [by downloading your Waze data](https://www.waze.com/account/download_data?mode=fresh). The downloaded archive contains your most recent alerts and interactions with the system, which might be enough information to share the data with the government(s) in a more "traditional" manner like a contact form or e-mail.

Comment: It looks like it is impossible for a non governmental institution to get this data. Maybe some scrapping from Live Maps? I'm a software developer

Comment: @neves the program is indeed reserved for governmental institutions only. I'm afraid I can't give any pointers on scraping data from the website due to the legal aspects surrounding that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if I can get data from a specific road or just from a region?

Comment: With Waze for Cities there is an area to define from which data is to be retrieved. For the personal Waze data, we're just talking about data being sorted chronologically by drive or by the time of the report creation. But to be clear: those are only your reports, not those you would've seen during the drive.